# How to move all files with extension to a subdirectory?

Tags: move

I have a directories in `/media/home/Seagate Expansion Drive/Downloads/Java Spring Gurus/folder1 .../folder2 .../foldern`

Inside every directory I have a `*.mp4` file and different types of additional files (*`.srt, *.pdf` etc.). I want to keep all `*.mp4` in `folderx`, create `folderx/rest/` and move the other files there.

How do I do that?

I tried:

```
for files in $(find "/media/sergio/Seagate Expansion Drive/DOWNS/Spring Framework 5"  | grep -P "([.]srt$)|([.]pdf$)")
do
  mv $files /resto
done
```

but I got a lot of errors

> mv: cannot stat

Comment: See [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697)

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see the use of using `find` here.  You know exactly where everything is so there's no need to go looking for files.

Instead, assuming that you're using the `bash` shell,

```bash
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s extglob dotglob

for dirpath in '/media/home/Seagate Expansion Drive/Downloads/Java Spring Gurus'/folder*/
do
    mkdir -p "$dirpath"/rest &&
    mv -i "$dirpath"/!(*.mp4|rest) "$dirpath"/rest
done
```

This would loop over all your `folder*` directories.  For each such directory, it would create a `rest` subdirectory within it and then move everything that doesn't match `*.mp4` (or the `rest` directory itself) into it.

The extended globbing pattern `!(*.mp4|rest)` would match any name not ending with `.mp4`, and not `rest`.

The shell options `extglob` enables the use of extended globbing patterns in `bash`, and the `dotglob` shell option will allow shell globs to match hidden names.

Answer (score 0):

This command should do what you expect:

```
find "/media/sergio/Seagate Expansion Drive/DOWNS/Spring Framework 5" -type f \! -iname '*.mp4' -execdir mkdir -p rest \; -execdir mv "{}" rest/  \;
```

In this command:

- `-type f`: only match files (avoid moving directories, symlink or special files)
- `\!`: act as a logic "NOT"
- `-iname`: select files matching on the name, case insensitive (Use `-name` if you want to match the case)
- `-execdir`: runs a command from the subdirectory containing the matched file. We need two of them, one for creating the folder `rest/` and the second one to move the file to it.

edit: add missing leading `\;`, use `execdir` and keep only one solution.

Comment: Excellent ! Almost there ! I learn a lot with your answer... I tried : find "/media/sergio/Seagate Expansion Drive/DOWNS/Spring Framework 5" -type f -iname '*.mp4' -exec mv "{}" /resto but I received this error here ... find: missing argument to `-exec'

Comment: Without the -exec mv "{}" /resto I can see all the files

Comment: Solved ! Thanks ! I google it and finished using it ... -/resto \;

Comment: Not really solved ! Moved to a /resto (where ???) and not to a subfolder resto in each folder. Could you help me please ?

Comment: @user2425924 i fixed the missing leading `\;`. 
Also, I think `-execdir` should do the trick for you.

Comment: Works fine thanks again. Solved question

Comment: Wouldn't this also create `rest` directories in each and every subdirectory of the `folder` directories?  I think there may also be a risk that `find` would potentially try to enter the newly created `rest` directory and create a _new_ `rest` directory within that.

Comment: I did it in a huge folder and worked as desired.